# Does Blazor's Edit Context requires the model to have public constructors?

Tags: blazor

Does Blazor's `Edit Context` from `<EditForm>` requires all the properties in the `Model` to have a public parameterless constructor to be able to work?
I have some Value Objects in the `Model` that have a private constructor (for validation reasons) and the `<EditForm>` doesn't get rendered at all.

EDIT: Example of model

```
public record Percent {
 public static Percent Zero = new Percent(0);
 public decimal Value {get;init;}


 // If I add this, it works
 public Percent(){}

 private Percent(decimal value){
   Value = value;
 }

 public static Percent Create(decimal value){
 ..validation..

 return new Percent(value);
 }
}

public class MyModel {

public Percent MyPercentProp {get;set;} = Percent.Zero;

}
```

(the following is overly simplified)

```
<EditForm Model="MyModelInstance">
  <PercentInput @bind-Value=@MyModelInstance.MyPercentProp />
</EditForm>

@code{
public MyModel MyModelInstance= new();

}
```

If i just add another public parameterless constructor, it works. Isn't there a workaround to this?

Comment: Have you tried making the ctor public temporarily?

Comment: Private property setters might cause problems too (just a guess).

Comment: Yes, and it works. But i'm wondering if there is a way to go around this behavior. It's not aright to expose that constructor in the whole codebase, since an object of that type shouldn't be able to be instantiated without any parameters or validation.

Comment: So the ctor is private but the property setters are public? Or can Blazor set properties even when the setters are private? Please show an example model.

Comment: Have you tried making the ctor `Percent(decimal)` public? That would be in line with your architecture requirements and maybe Blazor is smart enough to use it?

Comment: Can you add a sample of the EditForm ?  What do you bind to?   Va;ue is read-only.

Comment: It's simplified in the example. I'm actually returning an IResult<Percent> from the static factory method.  And yes, as long as there is a public constructor it works.

Comment: Yes, the edit control `OnChange` needs to set the value. Create an editable class that represents your record.  Use this class as the model.  On Save/Add create a new record that you submit to your backend.